# Strip String without whitespace

Tags: python

I have a string, and I want to split into three parts.

Eg:

```
s = 'fever=40'
```

I want to split `s` into `('fever', '=', '40')`.

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition

Comment: You can try a regular expression too, but do you want to split only on `=` character or want something more generic?

Comment: Can you give more examples? Do you want to split on punctuation? On the end of words? on the beginning on numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `partition` method for string objects:

```
>>> s = 'fever=40'
>>> s.partition('=')
('fever', '=', '40')
```

From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition):

> `str.partition(sep)`
>
> Split the string at the first occurrence of sep, and return a 3-tuple containing the part before the separator, the separator itself, and the part after the separator. If the separator is not found, return a 3-tuple containing the string itself, followed by two empty strings.

Comment: @AdrianCalin : If his answer was useful and answered your question it is proper etiquette accept his answer.